# What column type does django use for models.IPAddressField() in Sqlite3

Tags: django, django-models

I would try it myself, but I can't. Could someone check for me? I run Django 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get the correct answer:

```
from django.db import connection

for field in Model._meta._fields():
    print field, field.db_type(connection)
```

which on sqlite3 should give you something like this for an IPAddressField:

```
<django.db.models.fields.IPAddressField object at 0x101520410> char(15)
```

or if you're using multiple databases:

```
from django.db import connections

connection = connections['your_db_alias']

for field in Model._meta._fields():
    print field, field.db_type(connection)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Won't work, i'm trying to find the type it uses so i can manually create new databases using SQL scripts.

Comment: no error, just the field doesn't exist in any database and I couldn't get Django to make it for me. so (from what I understood of your code) there was no field to query the type of.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just an varchar(15). The definition of IPAddressField() doesn't change much of the normal Field behavior.